# Limit on number of redirects on Zeus web server

Tags: zeus

Does a Zeus web server have a limit on the number of redirects it can have in rewrite.script file?

As I have about 200 redirects in the file and it breaks about halfway down and there arn't any syntax errors as If I move some around they work again...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a limit. We haven't hit it yet and I'm pretty sure we have more than 200...